# how to dump latin1 encoded tables to utf8 encoded tables in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I can dump the data through phpmyadmin,
then use

```
$utf8 = iconv('latin1','utf-8//IGNORE',$latin1);
```

to convert it into utf8 encoding,

but see many messy code

Answer (score 1):

Please use "mb_convert_encoding "

example:

```
$utf8data = mb_convert_encoding($latindata,"utf-8","latin1");
```